# Standard way of getting a bit pattern of all ones

Tags: c, language-lawyer, bit-manipulation, bit

Is there a strictly conforming way to get a bit-pattern of all ones for an integer in C, without relying on implementation-defined behavior?

On many architectures I can expect `-1` and the `UINT_MAX` family to give such a bit pattern; how portable is this assumption?

Comment: What about the complement of zero? I.e. `~0`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Extremely portable. The C23 standard disallows integer representations that are not 2's complement, so then it will be guaranteed portable.

`~0` or `~0U` should always work.